# How to handle graphs and read graph data using selenium webdriver when graph loads using flash player

Tags: java, selenium, flash, webdriver

[image]

Here the graph loads using Adobe Flash Player. When I mouseover on the graph bar it displays some text data, I want to fetch that data automatically using Selenium Webdriver.

**Problem**: I am unable to inspect text on the graph.

Comment: If I understand your problem right, this might be a hidden element and can be clicked from script using `execute_script` property of the selenium driver.

Answer (score 0):

> *"...The graph loads using Adobe Flash Player. When I mouseover on the graph bar it displays some text data, I want to fetch that data automatically using Selenium Webdriver."*

Maybe Selenium Webdriver is the wrong tool for this task.

That Graph app (`.swf`) will getting its information from some other database (and then just displaying it as a graph). You need to access the same database / information. Usually this is stored in an **XML** or **JSON** file.

- Use the **Developer Tools** in your browser (I recommend Chrome) to check **Network** requests.
- Look for a new file (of type `.xml` or `.json`) being  added to the list when you refresh the chart or when you select new settings within the chart itself (*eg:* a new region).
- Whatever type of files requested, your required file will be text (or even HTML), so you can search and extract whatever you want from result by using `String` functions of Java.